# Как не показывать в браузере Flash, если устройство не поддерживает Flash?

Tags: javascript, html, flash

На сайте есть backgroind-image и есть flash.
Картинка background и flash одинаковые, flash накладывается сверху и добавляет анимации.

Вопрос: как не показывать flash, если устройство его не поддерживает, например, если зайти на сайт с android-устройства? Желательно средствами HTML.

Сейчас на android отображается прямоугольное серое окно с информацией, что flash не поддерживается.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сразу не добавлять flash, a проверить поддерживает ли устройство flash:

```
if(typeof swfobject !== 'undefined' && swfobject.getFlashPlayerVersion().major !== 0){}
```

если поддерживает подцепить с помощью javascript

Comment: Получилось, спасибо!